# import multiple wsdl from wcf with common namespace but different content

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I am trying to import several web services created from WCF into NetBeans 8.0.2 using Metro 2.3.1.

My problem is that the the web services (15 in all) share two common namespaces (common and core), but not all elements are represented in each web service's wsdl. That seems to mean that I can neither import the WSDL one by one as the common packages will be overwritten. Nor can I specify a binding that let me set schemaBindings using map=false, because there will be references to classes not imported. So, I guess I am looking for a way to merge the xsds for my import. Anyone who knows an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this post on the netbeans bug tracker :)

[Bug 148976 - Can't use multiple web service references from the same namespace](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=148976)

To apply the Wsimport customization just add a package option via the Wsimport Options pane in the Edit Web Service Attributes dialog.

click the add button set "package" as option name and (it's a sample :p) "com.rk.poc.sandboxed" as value ;)

Hope this help ;)

Regards,
a friend who wishes you well

Comment: Thank you, my friend :-)

Comment: (One cannot use <Enter> in this field :-o). But that seems to address the first part of my problem: When I import them into separate packages, I get two different definitions of the same class: com.rk.poc.ns1.Classx and com.rk.poc.ns2.Classx. And now I cannot use the objects across packages and I cannot cast objects to from one package's definition to the others (error saying that they are incompatible types!). Anyway, by now I have created facades for the whole thing and moved on, but it does mean that I am copying some amount of code.

Comment: This is a common problem. In our C# client we hab have exactly the same problem until we exclude common namespace from generated service reference and use directly on the client side the C# assemblies embedding theses common namespace définition. This is a handy feature provided by DotNet framework when we have control of both sides of the web service .

Comment: This is the Subject of the netbeans bug attaché to the provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have also find another way that seems to fulfill your need. To be tested ;)

https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/Compiling_multiple_WSDLs_that_share_a_common_schema.html

Comment: Tried that as well, both with wsimport and importing in netbeans, but the map=false for the schemaBindings means that I don't get all common/core classes and fail again. Anyway, I dropped solving it and put a facade on it.